# redirect users by language - too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect users with Chineses languages to the a domain using the following code in an .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (zh) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/under_c.html [L]
```

When I change my browser language to Chinese and test out the redirect it does go to the specified page, but it doesn't display anything it just gives me an error in the console that says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".  I've tried other solutions around the web but none of them seem to be able to redirect by language.

Is there a better way to redirect by language in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a rewrite loop you need to exclude `under_c.html` from the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (zh) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/under_c.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/under_c.html [R=302,L]
```